# React timer code is not working and outputting 2 everytime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-dom

Following is my code in which I am trying to print Date and time after every 1 sec, but I am getting output `2`. Let me know what I am doing wrong here and why it's outputting 2 every time -

Code - **App.js** File

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Elem() {
  return <p>{new Date().toISOString()}</p>
}

const TimeElem = () => {
  return setInterval(Elem, 1000)
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>Hello World</h3>
      <TimeElem />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Code - **index.js** File

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's outputting `2` because `setInterval(Elem, 1000)` will return interval `ID`, which is used when invoking `clearInterval(<ID>)`.

Considering this, here's working snippet based on your code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    interval: null,
    time: null
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ interval: setInterval(this.setTime, 1000) })
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.state.interval)
  }
  
  setTime = () => {
    this.setState({
      time: new Date().toISOString()
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.time}</div>
    );
  }
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id='root' />
```

Comment: May I ask you how to make this works in a jsfiddle? Because in the "run code snippet" it works, but in a jsfiddle it doesn't works, I think I'm missing something obvious

Comment: nevermind, I make it works I forgot to use babel + jsx in the javascript language, whops

Comment: @streletss Is it possible to make it working without lifecycle hooks ?

Comment: I guess you could `setInterval` in `render` only when `this.state.time` isn't set. But anyway you'd need to `clearInterval` at some point.

Comment: And if you're talking about keeping your stateless functional components, then react wouldn't be able to detect when `time` did change. you would need to `setState` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like the following:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    timer: ''
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.timer, 1000);
  }
  timer = () => {
    this.setState({
      timer: new Date().toISOString()
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h3>Hello World</h3>
        <span>{this.state.timer}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You just getting the result of `setInterval` function, not the result of `Elem`, and the result of `setInterval` is the id of interval that you can stop with `clearInterval` function.